# Is it possible to manipuate 3rd party Chrome Extensions Network Reqeuests?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am building a Chrome Extension that will call my backend APIs to validate something. I would like to know is it possible that other people could build some Chrome Extensions to manipulate the request and response to compromise the validation process? For example:

API: https://my-domain.com/validation

request:

```json
{
    "key": "aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd"
}
```

response:

```json
{
    "status": "IN_VALID_KEY"
}
```

Would someone is able to build a Chrome Extension to monitor requests on https://my-domain.com/validation and change the response to be

```json
{
    "status": "VALID"
}
```

Could that happen?

Comment: Only by using chrome.debugger API, which shows a warning while being used.